# Derive multiple df from single df such that each df has no NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert this table

```
0   thg   John     3.0
1   thg  James     4.0
2   mol    NaN     5.0
3   mol    NaN     NaN
4   lob    NaN     NaN
```

In this following tables

```
df1
movie   name  rating
0   thg   John     3.0
1   thg  James     4.0

df2
    movie  rating
2   mol     5.0

df3
    movie
3   mol  
4   lob
```

Where each dataframe has no Nan value, Also tell method if I need to separate with respect to blank value instead of Nan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that start of a new target DataFrame should occur not
only when the **number** of *NaN* values changes (compared to
previous row), but also when this number is the same, but
*NaN* values are in **different columns**.

So I propose the following formula:

```
dfs = [g.dropna(how='all',axis=1) for _,g in
    df.groupby(df.isna().ne(df.isna().shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum())]
```

You can print partial DataFrames (any number of them) running:

```
n = 0
for grp in dfs:
    print(f'\ndf No {n}:\n{grp}')
    n += 1
```

The advantage of my solution over the other becomes obvious when you add
to the source DataFrame another row containing:

```
5   NaN    NaN    3.0
```

It contains also **1** non-null value (like two previous rows).
The other solution will treat all these rows as one partial DataFrame
containing:

```
  movie  rating
3   mol     NaN
4   lob     NaN
5   NaN     3.0
```

as you can see, **with** *NaN* values, whereas my solution divides these
rows into 2 separate DataFrames, **without** any *NaN*.

Answer (score 2):

create a list of dfs , with a groupby and dropna:

```
dfs = [g.dropna(how='all',axis=1) for _,g in df.groupby(df.isna().sum(1))]
print(dfs[0],'\n\n',dfs[1],'\n\n',dfs[2])
```

Or dict:

```
d = {f"df{e+1}": g[1].dropna(how='all',axis=1) 
       for e,g in enumerate(df.groupby(df.isna().sum(1)))}
print(d['df1'],'\n\n',d['df2'],'\n\n',d['df3']) #read the keys of d
```

---

```
  movie   name  rating
0   thg   John     3.0
1   thg  James     4.0 

   movie  rating
2   mol     5.0 

   movie
3   mol
4   lob
```

Comment: What if instead of Nan I want to do with blank values.I want Nan should be present there.

Comment: @arunpal you mean without dropping the Nan?

Comment: Yes, Instead of Nan if blank value is criteria for deriving different df.

Comment: @arunpal `df.replace("",np.nan)` , i mean replace the blank first then